# I want to label the current date to a product But when I run the script later. I don't want to update the date. My script as below

Tags: javascript, date

I have a products array. By using map() method I want to add the current date in a new array. But later when I run this script, the time shouldn't be updated to the current date. So instead of `new Date()` what should I use? Imagine that you are getting some products and you are adding which date you got the product.
I don't want add the date by hand as string or timestamp.
Thank you in advance.

```
spareParts = ["Battery", "Alternator", "Radiator", "
Front Axle", "Brakes", "Muffler", "Tailpipe"];
function addDate(getArray) {

    const currentdate = new Date().toLocaleDateString() + '-' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString('de-CH', {
        hour: "numeric", minute: "numeric"
    });
    const newDAte = getArray.map(function (name) {
        return name + ' ' + currentdate;
    })

    return newDAte;
}
```

Output on console:

```
(7) ['Battery 12/22/2021-11:55', 'Alternator 12/22/2021-11:55', 'Radiator 12/22/2021-11:55', 'Front Axle 12/22/2021-11:55', 'Brakes 12/22/2021-11:55', 'Muffler 12/22/2021-11:55', 'Tailpipe 12/22/2021-11:55']
0: "Battery 12/22/2021-11:55"
1: "Alternator 12/22/2021-11:55"
2: "Radiator 12/22/2021-11:55"
3: "Front Axle 12/22/2021-11:55"
4: "Brakes 12/22/2021-11:55"
5: "Muffler 12/22/2021-11:55"
6: "Tailpipe 12/22/2021-11:55"
length: 7
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Here my problem is When I run this script after two days, the date and time shouldn't be updated to current date.

Comment: Please show an example of your question. What you are showing is something that is working for you - but you don't show how you're passing in the existing date, what format it is delivered and how you want it to look afterwards. Pls fill out your question a bit more

Comment: If the name includes a date, just return it. Otherwise, add the date. In pseudo code: `map( name => name has date? name : name + date)`.

Comment: I improved the question a bit more. You can see how output is supposed to be.